# router interface shows on public, instead of hosted website (ehcp)

Tags: networking, server, ftp, domain-server, hosting

I used EHCP for quick setup since im new to this, just dont understand how to setup the ip...
basically i can access my router from public ip, and my website only from my machine...

what could be the error in ip config, do I need to change my router or my config in ehcp ? there are no errors or anything i will dump my config which should be pretty... amateur

EHCP

```
Array gosteriliyor:
Array
(
    [dnsip] => 188.79.170.95
    [adminname] => user
    [adminemail] => email
    [ehcpdir] => /var/www/new/ehcp
    [banner] => this is banner.. you may write here something using server settings




    [defaulttemplate] => sky
    [defaultlanguage] => en
    [updatehostsfile] => Yes
    [messagetonewuser] => Dns servers for our server:

87.216.1.65

87.216.1.66



(This will be sent to new users)
    [backupdir] => /var/backup
    [quotaupdateinterval] => 6
    [webservertype] => apache2
    [webservermode] => nonssl
    [mysqlcharset] => DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci
    [enablewebstats] => Yes
    [versionwarningcounter] => 12
    [initialize_domain_files] => Yes
    [switchtoapacheonerror] => Yes
    [localip] => 127.0.1.1
    [lastquotaupdate] => 2018-10-08 09:19:33
    [activewebserverip] => 188.79.170.95
    [dnsipv6] => 
    [updatednsipfromweb] => Yes
    [morethanoneserver] => 
    [server_id] => 
    [disablecustomhttp] => Yes
    [disableeditwebservertemplate] => 
    [disableeditdnstemplate] => 
    [turnoffoverquotadomains] => 
    [userscansignup] => 
    [enablewildcarddomain] => 
    [freednsidentifier] => 
    [defaultdnsserverips] => 
    [defaultwebserverips] => 
    [defaultmailserverips] => 
    [singleserverip] => 188.79.170.95
)
```

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!   For those who don't know (because I didn't), EHCP is the Easy Hosting Control Panel as explained here: http://www.ehcp.net/helper/yardim/cat.php?cid=10  and there's a launchpad page here: https://launchpad.net/ehcp

Comment: Even though most of the website seems to reference 2008-2010, and most of the launchpad bugs are dated around then, there appears to have been a release in June 2018 for Ubuntu 18.04.  http://www.ehcp.net/?q=node/1861

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using that software was not a good idea since it's outdated. The answer would be to uninstall and use another LAMP solution.

To completely remove it do:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ehcp
```